# Error importing cxf projects into eclipse using m2e: Couldn't find that class org.apache.cxf.pmd.UnsafeStringConstructorRule

Tags: eclipse, maven, cxf, m2e, pmd

I check out the cxf sources and try to import a project into eclipse using "import as maven project".

I then get the error: Couldn't find that class org.apache.cxf.pmd.UnsafeStringConstructorRule
from m2e.

So it seems like cxf defines a rule there and the pmd plugin does not find it.
Any ideas?

Comment: try deleting the ruleset.xml file in your eclipse plugins directory in your workspace

Comment: Seems the file is recreated when I do maven .. update project

Comment: To get Eclipse to not flag the @SuppressWarnings("PMD") annotation, look under the menu headings Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Annotations -> Unhandled Warning Token. don't know if that helps?

Comment: there's a bug tracker for the maven 2 plugin here http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPMD

Comment: if you're not using 2 there's an faq here http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/pmd/faq.html

Comment: I dont think the issue is with the maven pmd plugin as it works on the command line. I think this rather has to do with m2eclipse.
Btw. I found a way to get rid of the error by removing the pmd config from the maven parent pom. Of course this is not the right way to solve it as I now do not get pmd checks anymore.

Comment: quite. curious question. i'm sure someone must know the answer. bounty!

Comment: try the below answer and see if it works

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to the [Apache CXF parent pom](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/trunk/parent/pom.xml), it mentions about the `profile` named `m2eclipse` which defines `maven-pmd-plugin` with `the dependency` as the following: -

```xml
<profile>
    <id>m2eclipse</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.build-utils</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-buildtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.build-utils.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>
                            ${cxf.resources.base.path}cxf-pmd-ruleset.xml
                        </ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
                    <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <excludeRoots>
                        <excludeRoot>${basedir}/src/main/generated</excludeRoot>
                    </excludeRoots>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

You may be noticed that there is no any `activation` in `this profile`.

After download the `org.apache.cxf.build-utils:cxf-buildtools:2.5.0:jar` form [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/cxf/build-utils/cxf-buildtools/2.5.0/cxf-buildtools-2.5.0.jar), I also have found the class named `org.apache.cxf.pmd.UnsafeStringConstructorRule` as well.

This may be the root cause of your problem. IMHO, you may try to activate this profile by missing some properties e.g.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>m2eclipse</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
           <name>!skipM2E</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    ....
</profile>
```

I hope this may help.